# Large number of open files Linux on Fluentd machine

Tags: linux, networking

I have several questions regarding a Ubuntu machine which I am working on.

First of all here is the output of max open files:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
1024000
```

However when checking how many are currently open:

```
$ lsof | wc -l
2002129
```

How is this number so much higer than the max?

Second, I had a look at what these open files were. 99% of them are these enteries:

```
ruby2.7 2749468 2750970 worker-14 fluentd 62u IPv4 1356781066 0t0 TCP {URL REDACTED}:5044->ip-10-153-7-71.eu-central-1.compute.internal:13637 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

There is a mix of CLOSE_WAIT and ESTABLISHED connections. But when I check with netstat or ss it does not show that many connections:

```
ss -a | wc -l
1447
```

What else can I do to investigate why fluentd is rejecting connections and the machine is killing connections which cause the log delivery to fail?

As a final example, this one is a little crude. Listing fd's in /proc doesnt show as many as how many lsof shows:

```
ls -l /proc/*/fd | wc -l
1109
```

Comment: `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` doesn't give max open files, but max open file descriptors. Open files don't necessarily have to have file descriptors (e.g. TCP connections, shared memory libs, current directory don't). `lsof` shows open files, while `ls /proc/*/fd` only shows file descriptors.

Comment: @stoney Ah ok. How can I check the max open files allowed on the system? And why is there a differnce between ss output and lsof showing TCP connections

Comment: As far as I know there is no such limit, it is per process and per user (see `ulimit`). Regarding TCP connections, did you use `netstat -alt|wc -l` and `ss -t state all|wc -l`?

Comment: @stoney Are you 100% sure tcp connections are not file descriptors? Any reference I can read up